# Not able to sign the transaction

Tags: transactions, stellar-sdk, multi-sig, sequence-number

I have created one multisig account with two co-signers. After that, I initiated two transactions back to back without signing using co-signers.

**Tx1** 10XLM – pending and **Tx2** 10XLM – pending.

Now, I tried to sign the **Tx1** using co-signers. But i couldn't do that. It's throwing error as `tx_bad_seq`. Then I checked the `seq.no` for both transaction. It is same.

Then again created one transaction and successfully signed the transaction using co-signers.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tx_bad_seq` error means that current source account `sequence` doesn't match the sequence specified in the transaction itself. Tx sequence [should be equal](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#sequence-number) to account sequence + 1 to pass the verification.

The account sequence is effectively a "nonce" intended to prevent transaction replay. It is incremented after each transaction. Failed transactions (for example, sending an asset without a trustline or submitting an invalid offer) also increment sequence for the source account.

Your second tx was applied successfully because you fetched current account sequence with something like `horizon.loadAccount(address)` before creating new transaction. The transaction builder uses this information to set a proper `sequence` for the transaction.

Comment: in my query, i have created three transaction. While am trying to sign the 1st two transaction which were in pending, its failing. but i can able to create and sign the third transaction. anyways, am using server.loadaccount(address) before creating new transaction

Comment: **A transaction will fail unless tx sequence number strictly equals current account sequence + 1**. Multisignature have nothing to do with this. You created a tx, then submitted some other transactions on behalf of the source account, so the first tx became invalid.

Comment: even second transaction also fail. i can sign only third transaction